# Sharing Singleton Services And Avoiding Circular Dependencies in Shared Components

Tags: angular, typescript

### The Tech Stack

This project is using Angular 2 and TypeScript running on a local NPM server and was built using the Angular CLI.

### The Architecture

This project has three modules in total.  The first one is for non-ui services and components. The second one is for UI components and layouts. And the third and final module is for UI services.  They are broken down as seen in the image below:

[image: Application Architecture]

As you can see, I'm really not sure whether I need a parent module here or not, hence the top-most item "? PARENT MODULE?"

### The Problems

1. Sharing a singleton of a service across multiple modules
2. Avoiding a circular dependency when two modules require each other to function

#### Problem 1 - Sharing a Service Singleton Across Multiple Modules

In my case, I need both the **UI module** and **non-UI module** to share singletons of all of the services in the **UI services module**.

#### What I Have Tried

So far I have tried using `forRoot()` to no avail, as well as attempting to move the services themselves to a parent module and provide them from there.  No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get both of the modules to share a singleton from the UI services module.

#### Problem 2 - Avoiding Circular Dependencies When Two Modules Require Each Other

The other problem I am facing in my application is that I have a part of one module that needs all of another module, which in turns needs the part of the first module in order to work.

In the non-UI module, you will see that the header/footer need to consume the UI module in order to function. However, in the UI module, the layouts need access to the header/footer in order to provide those items as part of the layout. This forms a circular dependency that I cannot quite wrap my head around eliminating.

#### What I Have Tried

I thought about moving the layouts out of the UI module into its own module, however they too need a reference to the components portion of the UI module, so if as soon as I import that module I create the circular dependency all over again.

### The Solution

I need a way to eliminate the circular dependency, and somehow share a singleton of all of the services in the UI services module between all other modules.

I have been trying to find a solution to these two problems for a week straight now, and I think at this point I can't see the forest for the trees.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, but I just can't seem to figure this problem out.

Comment: This structure will always have circular dependency. you can follow core, shared, features modules structure.

Answer (score 4):

Have a `CoreModule` that provides only services that do not depend on any other module, and that are expected to be singletons. This module should be imported by the root `AppModule` only. This will guarantee that those services are singletons (they are only provided in the `CoreModule`). In my app this is where I have global services such as `AuthService`. This will solve your singleton problem.

Have a `SharedModule` that exports components, directives and even Angular Modules that are shared by multiple modules. In my own app, this module includes components that I use all over, such as `DialogComponent`, or Angular's own `FormsModule` and `CommonModule`.  This `SharedModule` *does not* provide your global services. Import this module into every other module.  This will solve your circular dependencies problem.

In short, you can think of `CoreModule` and `SharedModule` as helper modules. On their own they don't build out your site, but they provide the dependencies needed by your site modules.  You may benefit from [reading this chapter](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule) of the docs, and then getting back to your project.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem because it would require moving the header/footer to a different module, which is not possible given my application architecture.  The pieces must remain where they are.  The only thing I can modify is where the imports and providers are.

Comment: @BeetleJuice you answer is correct, and follows the documentation.