# What is the proper way to avoid circular dependencies in Angular shared modules?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently trying to figure out the right decision for avoiding circular dependencies in Angular shared modules.

I have shared module in my project, which include all common angular modules i use across the project.

My shared module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatDialogModule
} from '@angular/material';

import { LoadingModule } from './components/loading/loading.module';

...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        MatSnackBarModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        ...
        
        LoadingModule        
    ],
    exports: [
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatIconModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        ...       
        LoadingModule
    ],
    providers: [...]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

And the LoadingModule, you can see here need some of dependesies from SharedModule.
I wonder, if somebody could provide a link for some good architectural style guide for managing such dependencies or help me with the right way of thinking. I have tried to look for something, but yet haven't found.
Thank's in advance for any answer.

Comment: I have founded something similar here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646266/sharing-singleton-services-and-avoiding-circular-dependencies-in-shared-componen, but this doesn't actually cover my case

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not hold the LoadingModule inside SharedModule, if you want to have some dependencies on SharedModule. Instead LoadingModule can be added to app.module.ts and it can be taken across the application.

Comment: Thanks, @PadmapriyaVishnuvardhan, it's really helpfull. But it seems i still have to import LoadingModule separately to my lazy-loading modules. maybe it is ok.